# Capture UTM parameters in Salesforce with live chat

Tags: liveagent, bots, livechattranscript, einstein-chatbot

I need a way to capture UTM parameters and create as lead in Salesforce with live chat.

Ex, if user started live chat or live agent and enquired somthing then I need to create a lead with UTM parameters.

Could you please help me with thoughts and experience.

If live chat and live agent won't work then how can I achieve this.

I need way to implement and steps would be great